# Formik validates initial values

Tags: reactjs, frontend, formik, react-typescript

The problem is that Formik calls `validate` method each time props are changed. I need to avoid this validation.
For now, my solution to this problem looks like this:

```
const ColumnsCustomizer = (
  {
    data,
    setData,
  }: {
    data: DataTableType | null;
    setData: (value: DataTableType | null) => void;
  }
) => {

  const deleteColumn = (index: number) => {
     some code here ...
  }

  const addColumn = (index: number) => {
     some code here...
  }


  return (
    <SidebarSection title="">
      {(data && data.rows) ? (
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize={true}
          initialValues={{
            headers: data.headers,
            maxIndex: data.headers.length,
            properties: data.properties
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setData({ ...data, headers: values.headers, properties: values.properties });
            setSubmitting(false);
          }}
          validateOnChange={true}
          validateOnBlur={false}
          validate={(values) => {
            if(JSON.stringify({  
              headers: data.headers,
              maxIndex: data.headers.length,
              properties: data.properties}) != JSON.stringify(values))
            setData({ ...data, headers: values.headers, properties: values.properties });
            return {};
          }}
        >
          {({ values }) => (
            <Form>
         so on...
```

Can I avoid deep equality check???

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent Formik from running validation on mount and when initialValues change by using `validateOnMount={false}`.

See: [https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateonmount-boolean`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateonmount-boolean%60)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was the first thing I tried :) Unfortunately, it didn't help